# matlab structure strange behviour gets 0 as root

Tags: matlab, user-interface, structure

I'm having this strange issue. In order to save all the values that I need of my gui I use structures. The bad part of this is that if I type S.var = 0 matlab doesn't get that the variable var is zero but it thinks that it's the root object!
How can I avoid that? I tried googling and in the help doc but nothing came out!

Comment: What is this `var`? if this is your root object it might be a `handle` class. In that case `S.var` is a **reference** to the root object and not a copy. If you just want to remove it, try `rmfield(S, 'var')`

Comment: @Shai I need a true/false variable but if I store it in a structure matlab thinks that, if false, is the root! That's my problem.

Comment: which version of Matlab are you using? In R2010a this seems to work fine...

Comment: @reverse_engineer I'm using R2012b

Comment: Could be an issue with that version... If you have a valid license (which I hope you do :)), you can contact Matlab Support by phone. They were very effective for me... (the Netherlands help center)

Comment: @reverse_engineer sometimes writing here it's easier and faster than the phone support, I'll try that anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `false` function instead of just assigning 0... So:

```
S.var = false;
```

This will return a logical zero, which should be what you want.

Comment: sorry already done that but it continues to think that it is zero. Maybe it is something under the hood